# 'TypeError: decoding str is not supported' when appending str in for loop within a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, list, data-science

I'm working on a job search web scraper but when converting a print statement into a return statement, I run into a 'TypeError: decoding str is not supported' even though this convertion formula works on a non-for-loop-within-a-for-loop.

I tried removing one of the str variables and this worked but what I need is a duple list including company and jobs

```
def get_company_and_jobs():
    """this function scrapes the company names 
    and job titles"""
    comps_and_jobs = []
    companyName = pageSoup.find_all('span', class_='company')
    jobTitle = pageSoup.find_all('div', class_='title')
    for span in jobTitle:
        for x in companyName:
            comps_and_jobs.append(str(x.text,span.text))
            # # This is before I added a list
            # print(x.text,span.text)
    return comps_and_jobs
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-9bcc02c8c200> in <module>
      4 for span in jobTitle:
      5     for x in companyName:
----> 6             comps_and_jobs.append(str(x.text,span.text))
      7             # # This is before I added a list
      8             # print(x.text,span.text)

TypeError: decoding str is not supported
```

Here is the same formula that I was copying the solution from:

```
def get_company_names():
    """this function scrapes the company names"""
    comp_names = []
    companyName = pageSoup.find_all('span', class_='company')
    for span in companyName:
        comps_names.append(str(span.text))
    ## This is before I added a list
    #     print(span.text)
    return comp_names
```

Is there a better way I could iterate over results to match both job and company in a list or dictionary?

Should I be using zip for this instead of a list?

Comment: You're passing two arguments to `str`.  The second argument, if present, is an encoding specifier, e.g. `'utf-8'` or something similar.  It looks like it's something else.

Comment: Thank you @TomKarzes, I added the formula I used and question there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being that I was passing two arguments, I simply split the arguments into two lines:

```
def get_company_and_jobs():
    """this function scrapes the company names 
    and job titles"""
    comps_and_jobs = []
    companyName = pageSoup.find_all('span', class_='company')
    jobTitle = pageSoup.find_all('div', class_='title')
    for span in jobTitle:
        for x in companyName:
            comps_and_jobs.append(str(x.text))
            comps_and_jobs.append(str(span.text))
    return comps_and_jobs
```